# DataTable expression Cannot interpret token '!'

Tags: c#, datatable, syntax-error, expression, token

I have the following code:

```
//myDataTable has the following collumns: UserName, Birthday and email.
string name = "eric!";
string expression = "UserName = " + name;
DataRow[] result = myDataTable.Select(expression);
```

I want to select all rows with the name "eric!".
The "!" gives me the following error:

> Cannot interpret token "!".

How can I select all rows with such tokens?
(I really need the "!" in the expression since I extract the userNames from a .sql file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use your `name` between `''`. Like;

```
string name = "'eric!'";
```

Without single quotes, your [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method thinks that `!` is an *operator* and it is not allowed in [`DataColumn.Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a valid operator.

From *documentation*;

> User-Defined Values
>
> User-defined values may be used within expressions to be compared with
>   column values. **String values should be enclosed within single
>   quotation marks.**

Answer (score 3):

You are missing quotes `(' ')` around your value

```
string name = "eric!";
string expression = "UserName = '" + name+'";
DataRow[] result = myDataTable.Select(expression);
```

When you write the filter operator without quotes and with `!`, it will consider `!` as *not operator* that's why it gives the error.