# How to select everything in a data table not equal to something?

Tags: c#, select, datatable

I have a data table with several columns. One of these columns has a certain value which I would like to use as a way to tell the program to either give me the row or tell it that I don't want the row.

My specific case is the column is called Status, and the *something* is APPROVED. So if the value in the Status column is something other than APPROVED I want it other wise don't bother me with it.

What I usually do in cases like this (but the opposite) is just use something like:

```
myDataTable.Select("Status = 'APPROVED'");
```

giving me everything that is APPROVED. But if I try with my intuition and write

```
myDataTable.Select("Status != 'APPROVED'");
```

I get

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SyntaxErrorException' in System.Data.dll
```

Note: from my debugging attempts, the only thing giving me an issue is the != operator. I wrap the statement with a try / catch and the exception reads:

```
Cannot interpret token '!' at position 8.
```

so using that output I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645666/datatable-expression-cannot-interpret-token). But it doesn't seem to help me much, trying as they suggested (a desperate attempt on my part):

```
myDataTable.Select("Status '!'= 'APPROVED'");
```

or

```
myDataTable.Select("Status '!=' 'APPROVED'");
```

first off doesn't make sense to me at all and more importantly doesn't work, which seems obvious to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `<>`

```
myDataTable.Select("Status <> 'APPROVED'");
```

Comment: This might be helpful (docs for DataTable.Select):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

There's a link there to how to use filter expressions:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/